# Serving static resources from external directories

Tags: jhipster

What should be the correct way to serve images, or any other static resources like css and javascript, from a directory existing outside of the application?

I used to achieve this very easily in Spring MVC applications by using the `mvc:resources` element in xml configuration, or by extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and adding the respective resource handlers in Java configuration, then specifying the file system path where the resources were stored.

Having in mind that, as far as I can tell, jhipster doesn't use Spring MVC how could I achieve this functionality?

I tried configuring Spring MVC in jhipster but introducing the `dispatcherServlet` only caused the application to break (as expected, right?), and I'm still getting the hang of Angular so I'm not sure if the solution is that way.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Added my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the magic of Spring Boot, now I know you can configure MVC related stuff by extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. So I created my own configuration class that overrides the corresponding method, in this case `addResourceHandlers` and it works like a charm.

Just note that the `@EnableWebMvc` is NOT needed, otherwise you will mess with JHipster front end.

Answer (score 0):

For dev just place the file in /src/main/webapp/yourdir/ and it should be served (assuming it's a public static resource). For production, you'd need to add it to the static filter in config/WebConfigurer.java:

```
/**
 * Initializes the static resources production Filter.
 */
private void initStaticResourcesProductionFilter(ServletContext servletContext,
                                                 EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps) {

    log.debug("Registering static resources production Filter");
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic staticResourcesProductionFilter =
            servletContext.addFilter("staticResourcesProductionFilter",
                    new StaticResourcesProductionFilter());

    staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/");
    staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/index.html");
    staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/images/*");
    staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/fonts/*");
    staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/scripts/*");
    staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/styles/*");
    staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/views/*");
    staticResourcesProductionFilter.setAsyncSupported(true);
}
```

Comment: My issue is that I'm working with a user-uploaded image repository that resides in a specific path in the file system, so I can't move it around. That's why I need to point to it, like I used to with Spring MVC.